# How do i open a file through a string in C

Tags: c, parsing, c-preprocessor, argv, argc

So im trying to use argc and argv to make a string and open a file through what I put into the command line but im getting:

> ```
> A3.c:14:30: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before string constant
> FILE *fopen(const char * "levelFile.txt", const char * "r+");
> ```

Also how do i go about parsing the file after this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < argc; i++)
  {
      printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
  }

  printf("%s", argv[1]);
  FILE *fopen(const char * "%s", const char * "r+", argv[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> FILE *fopen(const char * "%s", const char * "r+", argv[1]); // Wrong - you mixed up prototype with function call.

Should be:

```
  FILE *pFile = fopen(argv[1], "r+");  // declare a file pointer and initialize it to open the file with desired mode.
  if( NULL == pFile )  // check if file is opened ok.
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file");
  }
```

Comment: Ok so how can I then parse the file. I dont really understand what to do once i have the file opened. I need to take the data and store it in a struct.

Comment: You probably do not need the `r+` mode either, to just read the file, use `fopen(argv[1], "r")`

Comment: @chqrlie agree, but it's not specified whether he only reads the file or also update it.

Comment: @artm: indeed, I was actually addressing the OP, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change

```
FILE *fopen(const char * "%s", const char * "r+", argv[1]);
```

to

```
FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r+");
```

You are declaring a pointer to FILE, and a specfic variable name, such as `fp`, is called for.

Also, `fopen()` is a function call, which can only be an initializer. `"%s"` and `"r+"` are arguments, which don't need a leading `const char *`.